# Parallel scraping with puppeteer

Tags: node.js, mongodb, web-scraping, parallel-processing, puppeteer

Currently I have some code that is getting an array from mongodb. The scraper is looping through the array and is scraping from a website for each value in the array. My problem is that it's currently really slow. How would I be able to parallelize this so it scrapes more data at the same time?

Edit: Here's an example of a function I want to parallelize:

```
async function scrape(browser, page, i) {
//Start new Browser session
await page.setUserAgent('Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36');
await page.goto(dealer);

//Site specific code 
await page.type('.Search-bar-text-input', arrayOfArticles[i]);
await page.click('.Embedded-search-button')
await page.waitFor('.BuyingOptions-total', {timeout: 2000});


price = await page.evaluate(() => {
    price = document.querySelector('.BuyingOptions-total').innerText;
    console.log(price);
    return price;
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always use `child_process` or `cluster` to do it manually. Or You can use `node-pool` which is more automatic.

From this [issue](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/1873):

> ```
> const cluster = require("cluster");
> const numCPUs = require("os").cpus().length;
> const headless = true;
>
> let forks = numCPUs; // 4
>
> let browser;
>
> if (cluster.isMaster) {
>     for (let i = 0; i < forks; i++) {
>         cluster.fork();
>         console.log('Fork #' + i);
>     }
> } else {
>     connectToChrome();
> }
>
> function connectToChrome()
> {
>     (async function() {
>         let headless = false;
>         if (args.headless) {
>             headless = true;
>         }
>         browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: headless, args: ['--no-sandbox']});
>     })();
> }
> ```